# Create a common function with browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify

I'm pretty new to Browserify, I have more than a function that are used in different files. I'm refactoring my code to extract this function in a single file, so I have to maintain this source for those functions.
These functions are already used in my other files so I don't want to change the way I call them, so if I was using a function in this way

`var x= foo();`

I **don't want to change** the consumer javascript to something like

`var x= lib.foo();`

I created a file "./lib/common.js"

```
module.exports.trump = function (str, pattern) {
      var trumped = "";  // default return for invalid string and pattern

      if (str && str.length) {
        trumped = str;
        if (pattern && pattern.length) {
          var idx = str.indexOf(pattern);

          if (idx != -1) {
            trumped = str.substring(0, idx);
          }
        }
      }
      return (trumped);
        }

module.export.foo = function(options){
  return 1;
}
```

and in my app.js I have:

```
require('./lib/common.js')
trump(ui.item.PlaceId, "-sky" )
```

After browserifing my app.js file (no errors) I use it in my browser application, but I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: trump is not defined`

How should I export my functions using a single common.js file to make them work when simply calling them like `foo();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After requiring your library:

```
var common = require('./lib/common.js');
```

you can merge it into `this` using:

1. jQuery extend()

   ```
   $.extend(this, common);
   ```
2. Underscore.js extend()

   ```
   _.extend(this, common);
   ```
3. Object.assign() - ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard - Check browsers compatibility

   ```
   Object.assign(this, common)
   ```
4. An `Object.assign` polyfill (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

   ```
   if (!Object.assign) {
       Object.defineProperty(Object, 'assign', {
           enumerable: false,
           configurable: true,
           writable: true,
           value: function(target) {
               'use strict';
               if (target === undefined || target === null) {
                   throw new TypeError('Cannot convert first argument to object');
               }

               var to = Object(target);
               for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                   var nextSource = arguments[i];
                   if (nextSource === undefined || nextSource === null) {
                       continue;
                   }
                   nextSource = Object(nextSource);

                   var keysArray = Object.keys(nextSource);
                   for (var nextIndex = 0, len = keysArray.length; nextIndex < len; nextIndex++) {
                       var nextKey = keysArray[nextIndex];
                       var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(nextSource, nextKey);
                       if (desc !== undefined && desc.enumerable) {
                           to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
                       }
                   }
               }
               return to;
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: Is this a good practice? There is any drawback on doing this?

Comment: Best practice would be to have functions in their modules. But since you want to call them directly you have two options: 1) attaching them to the `window` object or 2) merging them into `this`. Acting on `this` should be generally speaking less dangerous than manipulating the global `window` object. In both cases anyway you risk to overwrite existing functions.